# jQuery UI Draggable Clone Helper Disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have draggable working on an element. When I drag it, the desired effect I want is a ghost outline of the element as I drag, then on mouseup, the element moves to the offset of where I let the mouse go. So i guess I need to use helper clone? However, on mouseup, the ghost disappears and the element doesn't move to a new position.

```
$('.container').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

I've seen some answers using a drag and drop target. I'm not dragging my element into a specific area though, I want to be able to drag it anywhere on the screen, continuously. Is drag and drop not overkill?

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjc54/1/).

Answer (score 1):

What version of Jquery UI are you using? Does the problem only happens when the page is scrolled? I have noticed a similar problem when upgrading from 1.9.1 to 1.10.3 the clone position seems to be computed from the top of the screen and no more from the top of the page. So you may see the clone much lower the place it should be.

I have personnaly switched back to 1.9.1

Comment: I've updated the question with a JS fiddle. As you can see, when you let go of the mouse, the clone disappears. I want the element to move to wherever I drag it.

Comment: I ran into the problem you're describing here today. It seems this bug is still not fixed as of version 1.12.1. Version 1.9.2 works.